# Can add Tab hotkey to my shell script?

Tags: shell-script, autocomplete

Can I use Tab hotkey in my shell to auto-completion where have an input

just like this:

[image]

when I input "test" and tap Tab hotkey,"test" will auto-completion become "test.md".

Welcome suggestions, please!

Comment: That is likely to depend on the particular shell you're using -- I assume you're using `#!/bin/bash` and are reading the filename with `read`?

Comment: hi ,shell bash is #!/bin/bash,and below is my shell 
#!/bin/bash
echo "--------------------------"
ls -lrt| tail -3 | while read line;do echo "$line"; done
echo "--------------------------"
read -p "Please input .md file you want push:" file
git add $file
git commit -m "add $file"
git push origin master
echo "$file push successed!"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rlwrap` to add readline support (including completion and history/recall) to almost any command line program, including shell scripts.

See `man rlwrap` for more details, and/or edit your question to include a minimal sample shell script if you want more specific advice on using rlwrap with it.

`rlwrap` is packaged for most linux distros, and you can find the source at https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap

BTW, the description field of debian's rlwrap package says:

> Description-en: readline feature command line wrapper  This package
>   provides a small utility that uses the GNU readline library  to allow
>   the editing of keyboard input for any other command.  Input  history
>   is remembered across invocations, separately for each command; 
>   history completion and search work as in bash and completion word
>   lists  can be specified on the command line.

BTW, one useful thing mentioned in the man page is:

> In a shell script, use rlwrap in 'one-shot' mode as a  replacement 
>   for read
>
> ```
> order=$(rlwrap -pYellow -S 'Your pizza? ' -H past_orders -P Margherita -o cat)
> ```

That would be as a substitute for something like `read -p 'Your order? ' order`